# Can't evict from Spring Cache in Guice DI app

Tags: spring, caching, guice

I'm trying to use String Cache abstraction mechanism with guice modules.
I've created interceptors:

CacheManager cacheManager = createCacheManager();
        bind(CacheManager.class).toInstance(cacheManager);

```
    AppCacheInterceptor interceptor = new AppCacheInterceptor(
            cacheManager,
            createCacheOperationSource()
    );

    bindInterceptor(
            Matchers.any(),
            Matchers.annotatedWith(Cacheable.class),
            interceptor
    );

    bindInterceptor(
            Matchers.any(),
            Matchers.annotatedWith(CacheEvict.class),
            interceptor
    );
```

Then, implemented Strings Cache interface and CacheManager, and finally annotated my DAO classes with @Cachable and @CacheEvict:

```
public class DaoTester {

QssandraConsumer qs;

@CachePut(value = "cached_consumers", key = "#consumer.id")
public void save(QssandraConsumer consumer) {
    qs = consumer;
}

@Cacheable(value = "cached_consumers")
public QssandraConsumer get(String id) {
    if (id != null) {
        qs.getId();
    }
    return qs;
}

@CacheEvict(value = "cached_consumers", key = "#consumer.id")
public void remove(QssandraConsumer consumer) {
    qs = consumer;
}}
```

Caching is simply fine - no problems here, but when i try to evict(calling remove method in this example), evrything crashes and I see:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 10): Field or property 'id' cannot be found on null
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator.key(ExpressionEvaluator.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectAfterCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
>       at qiwi.qommon.deployment.dao.DaoTester.main(DaoTester.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

What's wrong here?!
BTW, cached object is:

```
public class QssandraConsumer implements Identifiable<String> {
private String id;
private String host;

@Override
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) {
        return true;
    }
    if (null == object) {
        return false;
    }


    if (!(object instanceof QssandraConsumer)) {
        return false;
    }

    QssandraConsumer o = (QssandraConsumer) object;

    return
        Objects.equal(id, o.id)
            && Objects.equal(host, o.host);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(
        id, host
    );
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
        .addValue(id)
        .addValue(host)
        .toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what was the reason of the problem:
when injecting a class that uses annotation(which are intercepted, like `@Cachable` or `@CacheEvict`) Guice enhances class (AOP make bytecode modification in runtime). So when `CacheInterceptor` tryed to evaluate `key = "#consumer.id"` it failed because couldn't find argument name in enhanced class (see: `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer#inspectClass`).
So it will not work in Guice out of the box.
In spring the proxy class is created - so no problems here.